# What does "you can blow it out some vans" mean?

Tags: word-meaning

First off, ditch the running shoes, you can leave bare foot, or if your gym allows that I will get some chuck Taylor, some wrestling shoes, you can blow it out some vans~!

What does "you can blow it out some vans" mean?

I know vans is a name of shoes brand, but I don't get it that last part "you can blow it out some vans." Does it mean you can even wear vans while you are working out?

Actually I heard this from a youtube video, at 01:07, this guys said those, but I really don't get it "blow it out some vans".

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y1IGeJEXpF4

Is this a sort of unborn word?

Comment: Can you tell us what this is from? It looks very informal... Some context may help us answer your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What he says  is

> You can lift barefoot, or, if your gym doesn't allow that, I would get some old Chuck Taylors ... some wrestling shoes ... or you can **bro it out with some Vans**.

meaning approximately "You can demonstrate your adherence to conventional standards of masculinity by wearing Vans."

*Bros* are unrelated 'brothers': a young man's male friends with whom he shares stereotypically male interests such as athletics, drinking, and loud aggressive by-play. See Wikipedia [Bro (subculture)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bro_(subculture)). To *bro it out* means to behave or to present yourself like a bro.

Comment: ..and _Vans,_ of course, are a brand of shoes that one might expect _bros_ to wear.